# Setformatter(new NumericMonthFormatter()) & SetDisplayValues(null) are not working in Android version 5.1.1

Tags: android, xamarin.android, datepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

```
 NumberPicker numberPicker;
            if (datePickerNumericMonthFormat)
            {
                var input = numberPicker.FindViewById<EditText>(Activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/numberpicker_input", null, null));
                input.SetRawInputType(global::Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber);

                if (monthSpinnerResId != 0)
                {
                    if (onCreateEventOrNot)
                    {
                        numberPicker = dialog.DatePicker.FindViewById<NumberPicker>(monthSpinnerResId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numberPicker = view.FindViewById<NumberPicker>(monthSpinnerResId);
                    }
                    numberPicker?.SetFormatter(new NumericMonthFormatter());
                    numberPicker?.SetDisplayedValues(null);
                    numberPicker.Invalidate();
                }
            }

public class NumericMonthFormatter: Java.Lang.Object, NumberPicker.IFormatter
        {
            public string Format(int value)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:D2}", (value + 1));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am getting "Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
  Message=setSpan (3 ... 3) ends beyond length 2" error but working in higher version of Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code on different versions of Android. It can work well on the device which Android version is >= Android 7.1. And since the Android version 7.0 and lower. The error will appear.

And I also converted your code to java and tested it in the native android project with the Android Studio. The result was the same.

[image]

It should be a bug in the native andorid. You can report it on the [Google Android Community](https://support.google.com/android/community?hl=en).

In addition, the code caused this error is `numberPicker?.SetDisplayedValues(null);`. If you delete this line or use the following code, it can run on all the android versions.

```
string[] arrays = new string[] { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" };
numberPicker?.SetDisplayedValues(arrays);
```

Comment: Hi Liyun & Mike
Thanks both of you for your help & yes it is working stringArray appraoch but I am finding other approach with SetFormatter(new NumericMonthFormatter()) & monthPicker.SetDisplayedValues(null) methods. Yes you're correct it is native android bug